# Difference in javascript regex behaviour from online tools and in actual code

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am using http://regexr.com/3duh0 this regex

```
(?:\S+\s)?\S*Environment Canada\S?
```

on this string

> Flash Flood Watch in effect until Friday, 2:00 AM EDT.  Rainfall
>   Warning in effect until 8:40 PM MDT.  Source: Environment Canada

and while it works all fine and dandy online when i apply that to my code it acts differently and i can't make heads or tails why.

I am using node 0.10.32 (I know, but i have no choice on the version),

```
var regexFindSource= new RegExp('(?:\S+\s)?\S*Environment Canada\S?');
var summary = 'Flash Flood Watch in effect until Friday, 2:00 AM EDT.  Rainfall Warning in effect until 8:40 PM MDT.  Source: Environment Canada'
source = summary.match(regexFindSource);
console.log(source);
//The results of this bit of code are
//What i want is 'Source: Environment Canada'
//What i get is 'Environment Canada'
```

The reason i am basing the regex on Environment Canada is because i want to insert a variable in the place of Environment Canada something like this

```
var source = wwArray.Source;   
var regexFindSource= new RegExp('(?:\S+\s)?\S*' + source + '\S?');
```

Comment: Use `var regexFindSource= /(?:\S+\s)?\S*Environment Canada\S?/` or else double escape `\s`, `\S` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a '\' before \S* and a ': 'after

```
var regexFindSource= new RegExp('(?:\S+\s)?\\S*: Environment Canada\S?');
var summary = 'Flash Flood Watch in effect until Friday, 2:00 AM EDT.  Rainfall Warning in effect until 8:40 PM MDT.  Source: Environment Canada'
source = summary.match(regexFindSource);
console.log(source);
```

For your edit:

```
var source = wwArray.Source;   
var regexFindSource= new RegExp('(?:\S+\s)?\\S*: '+ source +'\S?');
var summary = 'Flash Flood Watch in effect until Friday, 2:00 AM EDT.  Rainfall Warning in effect until 8:40 PM MDT.  Source: Environment Canada'
source = summary.match(regexFindSource);
console.log(source);
```